# Wordpress - Query post from favorited author

Tags: php, wordpress

I use a third party plugin called "Favorite Author". I want to filter posts with the author I favorited. I tried this :

```
$fav_author_list = get_user_option( 'favorite-authors', fav_authors_get_user_id() );
print_r($fav_author_list);
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; 
query_posts( array( 'author__in'=> array_keys($fav_author_list) , 'paged' => $paged, ) );
```

That prints something like :

```
Array (
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1
)
```

Where 3 and 1 are the user ID I follow. But the displayed posts don't match with the author I favorited. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_keys` will return the keys from the array, not the values. Just pass the `$fav_author_list` array directly and it should work.

```
$fav_author_list = get_user_option( 'favorite-authors', fav_authors_get_user_id() );
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; 
query_posts( array( 'author__in'=> $fav_author_list, 'paged' => $paged, ) );
```